# AssetsLibrary does not get images saved in the Camera roll when I run the program on the device

Tags: objective-c, ios4, assetslibrary

I wrote a simple iOS program to get number of photo images which are saved in the camera roll by using 'Assets Library' framework provided in the SDK4.2.

The program worked well as I expected when I ran it on the iPhone simulator.
But, it didn't retrieve any images when I ran on the 'real' iPhone device (iPhone 3GS with iOS 4.2.1).

This problem looks like as same as the problem discussed in the below article: 
[Assets Library Framework not working correctly on 4.0 and 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200552/assets-library-framework-not-working-correctly-on-4-0-and-4-2)

So, I added the "dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()..." function as below, But I couldn't solve the problem.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableArray assets = [[NSMutableArray array] retain]; // Prepare array to have retrieved images by Assets Library.

    void (^assetEnumerator)(struct ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
        if(asset != NULL) {
            [assets addObject:asset]; 
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                // show number of retrieved images saved in the Camera role.
                // The [assets count] returns always 0 when I run this program on iPhone device although it worked OK on the simulator.
                NSLog(@"%i", [assets count]);
            });
        }
    };

    void (^assetGroupEnumerator)(struct ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) =  ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
        if(group != nil) {
            [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
        }
    };

    // Create instance of the Assets Library.
    ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos // Retrieve the images saved in the Camera role.
                           usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
                         failureBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
                             NSLog(@"Failed.");
                         }];
}
```

Could you please tell me if you have any ideas to solve it?

Comment: Finally I got solution for this problem:

Answer (score 0):

I have 1 update:

To get error code, I modified the failureBlock of the enumerateGroupsWithTypes as below, and then reproduced the symptom again.

Then, the app returned the error code -3311 (ALAssetsLibraryAccessUserDeniedError).
However I didn't any operation to deny while my reproducing test.

What's the possible cause of the err#=-3311?

```
[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos
                       usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
                     failureBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
                         NSLog(@"Failed");
        resultMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Failed: code=%d", [error code]];                     }];
```

Comment: Finally I got solution for this problem.

I had to enable the "location service" to make this program works well.

Here is the steps;

(1) Install the above app to iPhone device.
(2) Launch the [Settings] and go to [General] > [Location Services] > [<my-app-name>] to turn it "ON".
(3) Launch my app to run it.

Then my app retrieved the photos from camera roll as I expected.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Ya it asks for location services but the behaviour is strange as why would an image fetch require location services. Is there any way i can do without turning  my location services on and not being asked for location services to be allowed when i am fetching the photos in my app??

Comment: @chotachetan photos have location data associated.  Accessing the photos through this mechanism allows you to also access the location data, therefore the user must permit your app to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It is strange that location services should be involved when accessing saved photos. Maybe it has to do with geo-tagging information on the photos. Anyways Apple says that enabling location services is required when using [`enumerateGroupsWithTypes:usingBlock:failureBlock:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

**Special Considerations**
This method will fail with error `ALAssetsLibraryAccessGloballyDeniedError` if the user has not enabled Location Services (in Settings > General)."